# Insert a concat into an existing table in sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert, concatenation

I have a table thats called Rooms with columns

```
NumberOfRoom | InBuilding | NameOfRoom
22           | D          | D22
54           | B          | B54
51           | E          | E51
```

I would like to concat the numberOfRoom with InBuilding so the result would be The NameOfRoom

The table is already created and i would like to insert the data in that table except that my problem here is when i insert the values with the concat demand there is an error that tells me the value cannot be null

```
insert into Rooms (NumberOfRoom , InBuilding , NameOfRoom) 
      values (22, 'D', (select concat (NumberOfRoom , InBuilding) as NameOfRoom
                        from Rooms)
             );
```

The result should look like: 22D or D22 (the order doesnt matter).

EDIT: Also all the columns are mandatory so none of the columns can be NULL. The table can consist of more than three columns, e.g. there would be another column after the column nameOfRoom, for example column capacity

```
NumberOfRoom | InBuilding | NameOfRoom| capacity
22           | D          | D22       | 10
54           | B          | B54       | 4
```

Is there a solution for this or another way to merge these two columns with another command?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INSERT INTO . .  SELECT` statement without `VALUES` :

```
INSERT INTO Rooms (NumberOfRoom , InBuilding , NameOfRoom) 
    SELECT 22, 'D', CONCAT(NumberOfRoom, InBuilding) AS NameOfRoom 
    FROM Rooms;
```

You can also make it dynamic :

```
SELECT NumberOfRoom, InBuilding, CONCAT(NumberOfRoom, InBuilding) AS NameOfRoom 
FROM Rooms;
```

However, after reading your whole question again i found you may need `UPDATE` rather than `INSERT` if so, then you can do :

```
UPDATE Rooms 
    SET NameOfRoom = CONCAT(NumberOfRoom, InBuilding)
```

Comment: Only my problem is that the table is already created and the columns are mandatory and need to be filled. The table also doesn't have only these three columns but another columns that maybe are irrelevant to these columns but are mandatory for the table also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `virtual column` concept as following:

```
create table rooms (
numberofroom number,
inbuilding varchar2(100),
nameofroom generated always as (inbuilding||numberofroom)
);
```

[Db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4cbcb9df4ee7f97d5798e2dc92c6956a)

Cheers!!

Comment: what if the table consists of more columns, e.g. there would be column capacity after column nameofroom, what should i put into the values in the insert?

Comment: You can always use column names and insert respective values. `insert into table(col1, col2, .. col99) values (val1, val2,... val99)`. Order of the column doesnt matter here just make sure that mapping of col and val is correct and always omit `nameofroom` column from your insert.